# Why does the Windows SDK now include strmbase.lib?

Tags: visual-c++, directshow

Windows SDK 7.1 was the last version that included the baseclasses direct show sample. But later Windows SDK have strmbase.lib with the compiled library. What use is the library without the headers?

Answer (score 2):

It might be included without good reason waiting for its cleanup time, or there is unobvious reason such as reference to this static library when linking other legacy libraries.

Either way you are correct in the part that DirectShow bases classes are no longer in Windows SDK. Those interested in DirectShow development would typically get DirectShow BaseClasses and samples from [Windows-classic-samples/Win7Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses) and build the code including `strmbase.lib` themselves.